# use object.property inside predicate function from cdk drag drop

Tags: angular, scope, reference, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

Lets look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nc9gnc):

I want the list to be dropable based on a object.property.

Somehow it only works as expected when I use a public static variable.

- Have a look in the `dynamicPredicate()` function.

I have a feeling why this is not working as expected:
the predicate Function is shipped as is to the directive and is evaluated there.

**How can make the predicate function work with object properties?**

Answer (score 2):

The solution was quite easy!

I have to use an es6 arrow function:

```
dynamicPredicate2 = () => { return this.defaultBool }
```